# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ be a continuously differentiable function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

**Problem:** Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ be a continuously differentiable function. Prove that there exists $\xi \in (0,1)$ such that$$e^{f'(\xi)} \cdot f(0)^{f(\xi)} = f(1)^{f(\xi)}$$

**Approach towards Solution:** let's define $g(x)$ such that
\begin{align*}
    \ln{f(x)} = g(x) 
\end{align*}
The map $g$ is well defined as $\text{range}( f) = (0, \infty)$.

Then by MVT on $g(x)$ in $[0, 1]$ we have that $~\exists~ \xi \in (0, 1)$ such that
$$ g'(\xi) = \frac{f'(\xi)}{f(\xi)} = \frac{\ln f(1) - \ln f(0)}{1 - 0} = \ln\left( \frac{f(1)}{f(0)} \right) \implies e^{f'(\xi)} \cdot f(0)^{f(\xi)} = f(1)^{f(\xi)} $$

---

Does this seem right? Are there any issues or glitches in the solution technique?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just read the statement of your problem without looking to the solution you proposed, after awhile I came up with the same solution. Yes your solution is Ok. It is enough to assume $f$ is differential.